# Order of Function Definitions and Referenced Before Assignmnet Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

Suppose we have the following two snippets of code:

Snippet #1:

```
def bar():
   print("Hello world")
   baz()

def baz():
   print("Hello user")

bar()
```

Snippet #2:

```
def bar():
   print("Hello world")
   baz()
   
   def baz():
      print("Hello User")

bar()
```

Here, we have two different scenarios:

In the first snippet, we create two functions `bar` and `baz`. More specifically, `bar` is created before `baz` and `baz` is called within our function definition of `bar`. After both definitions, we call `bar`, which executes without error.

In the second snippet, we also create two functions `bar` and `baz`. However, `baz` is nested within the function of `bar`. After both definitions, we call `bar`, which will not execute due to a reference error with `baz`.

Why does the second snippet of code not work? I understand that it is because `baz` is referenced before assignment, but we also reference `baz` before assignment in the first snippet and it works.

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Comment: *Writing* a reference to a not-yet-defined value is not a problem.  It's *actually executing* the code containing the undefined reference that causes an error.

Comment: So, in this context, how would that insight apply? @jasonharper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "*compile time*", Python takes a note of local variables inside the function. Those are all the parameters and also all the symbols that you assigned them to something (`var = ?`).

In "*runtime*", Whenever you ask it to look for a name, if that name is noted as a local variable, it only checks the local namespace to find it.

```py
a = 10
def fn():
    print(a)
    a = 20
fn() # UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'a' where it is not associated with a value
```

When we execute `print(a)`, there is no `a` in the local namespace.

Defining a function is nothing more that just assigning a function name to a function object. These are the same:

```py
def fn():
    ...

fn = lambda: ...
```

So that rule applies here too.

Here:

```py
def bar():
   print("Hello world")
   baz()
   
   def baz():
      print("Hello User")

bar()
```

When you lookup `baz`, Python already knows that `baz` should be a local variable, but it can't find it because it's not defined yet which means it's not in the local namespace.

You should note that, even if you have another `baz` defined at global level, your code would not work either. Again because it's noted that `baz` should be found in local namespace:

```py
def baz():
    print("hello")


def bar():
    print("Hello world")
    baz()

    def baz():
        print("Hello User")


bar()
```

In the first case, you didn't assign the name `baz` to anything, `baz` is not a local name, so Python looks for it in another place(global namespace in this case).

Comment: While your explanation clarifies why the second snippet does not work, I am still having difficulty understanding why the first snippet does work. By the same logic you applied to snippet two, the interpreter would know that ```baz``` is a global variable. However, ```baz``` would not be found when the interpreter would look for it in the global namespace (since it has not been defined yet). Why, then, does no error result? @S.B

Comment: @LateGameLank Of course it is in the global namespace. First you create `bar` function, then you create `baz` function (up until now, those two functions are in global namespace), then you call `bar` function. At the time `bar` is being called, `baz` is in the global namespace.